# Transition is not smooth when hiding UIKeyboard that covers UITableVIew

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

I have been following this apple tutorial, about keyboard that covers fields when its shown:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Everything works fine except when keyboard is hidden, my `UITtableView` is just resized, cut so to speak to proper dimension, there is no smooth transition. When using `UITableViewController`, this effect is much smoother, you can clearly see how to view scrolls down, it doesn't just shrink immediately.

Is there any advice on this?

EDIT:

I'll try to be more precise. When user taps one of the text fields keyboard is shown and this method gets called:

```
- (void) keyboardWasShown: (NSNotification*) keyboardNotification {
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [keyboardNotification userInfo];
 CGSize size = [[userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
 UIEdgeInsets insents = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, size.height - 44, 0); // 44 because keyboard goes over toolbar 

 self.revisionTableView.contentInset = insents;
 self.revisionTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insents;
}
```

After i am finished with editing i tap done button on keyboard and keyboard hides. During that this method is called:

```
 - (void) keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification*) keyboardNotification {
 UIEdgeInsets insents = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
 self.revisionTableView.contentInset = insents;
 self.revisionTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insents;
}
```

Although everything is returned to previous state, the transition is not smooth, as when i tap done button on keyboard when i am using `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and its just not clear what the problem is. Normally you do not resize a table when the keyboard appears - you might scroll it up so that the cell you are editing is at the top of the screen, or above he keyboard, and when the keyboard slides down, you animate the table back to the place it was when you started. People all over the world are doing this. I know of no reason a UITableViewController subclass should do this any better than a UIViewController subclass.